# Crash - dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSDK.framework/AWSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, airwatch, airwatchsdk

I searched a lot but not getting a developer friendly document to integrate AirWatch for SSO login in my App.

I am trying to integrate AWSDK in iOS (Objective C) by following this instruction (https://developer.vmware.com/web/workspace-one/tutorials/Native-iOS/Airwatch-SDK). I am stuck with this crash as mentioned below during app launch.

How can I resolve this?

Crash reason on Xcode console:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSDK.framework/AWSDK

  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E822D5BB-D44D-444E-8201-20E211E1A493/AirWatchSample.app/AirWatchSample

  Reason: image not found

dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection

DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib

Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6
```

Comment: Double check the part "Adding Linker Flags" & "Adding the AirWatch SDK Frameworks", I guess there is an issue there...

Comment: @Larme I have already added the "Other Linker Flags" as "-ObjC". Do I need to add something else? Please suggest. Anyway thanks for your effort